# Nohup does not work in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, nohup

Bash:

```
$nohup sleep 10 &
```

but when I close the terminal:

[image: will exit warning]

Any ideas? ideally I want to run Mongodb in the background.

Comment: Works for me here - check your terminal preferences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting. Seems like an issue specific to the default Terminal app. Because for what it's worth, [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) doesn't exhibit this behavior. (so in other words, `nohup` is not actually broken on OS X; this just seems like special behavior in Terminal which looks for subprocesses on exit.)

In many ways, iTerm2 it's better than the default terminal. You should give it a try!

Comment: You're right, it's a quirky display error that I guess didn't get Apple's attention yet. iTerm is interesting, thanks for the link!

Comment: This definitely is not my experience.  If I `nohup emacs &` in term2, when/if I kill iterm, emacs goes with it.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this on Snow Leopard, and the dialog popped up and complained that it was going to kill sleep, but when I checked via `ps -eaf` sleep was still running.

```
bill$ ps -eaf | grep sleep
  501 11806     1   0   0:00.00 ??         0:00.01 sleep 1000
  501 11811  2628   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.00 grep sleep
```

Answer (score 2):

Running it in a `screen` session should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on OSX 10.8.5, and can confirm:

`nohup base64 /dev/urandom &`

Terminal.app-based apps (eg TotalTerminal) spawns the process under the shell session, not under `launchd`, which would be the expected/equivalent to linux behaviour.

On the other hand, iTerm2.app was able to run the same command under `launchd`, and it kept alive after the shell session was closed. It implements some special trick though:

```
─┬◆ 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 ├─┬◆ 00245 albanj01 /sbin/launchd
 │ └─┬◆ 21533 albanj01 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 -psn_0_94628409
 │   └─┬◆ 04684 albanj01 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
 │     └─┬◆ 04685 albanj01 -zsh
 │       └──◆ 04759 albanj01 base64 /dev/urandom
```

My colleague on my side has tried the same thing on OSX 10.10.x and Terminal.app spawned the `nohup` process under `launchd`, suggesting that potentially they have fixed it between 10.8.x-10.10.x .

Comment: How do you get this kind of tree?

Answer (score 1):

use tmux

```
brew install tmux

tmux
```

use "tee" command to store output to txt

```
python hello.py | tee -a ~/Downloads/output.txt
```